# Blank Items in CheckBoxList (Remove blank items)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, checkboxlist, listitem, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a rather irritating and silly problem. I have a checkbox list on a asp page that I populate from a database. I am able to populate it, the problem lies when I do a specific check that checks if the users are active or not, it displays only the ones that are active but then leaves huge blanks in my control of where the original not active users were displayed.

I have pictures of before and after I implement that specific if statement:
here is the code for populating and checking:

```
    this.AddMultipleUsers.Items.Clear();
    foreach (GetAllLoginUsersResult result in from a in this.db.GetAllLoginUsers(null)
                                              orderby a.FirstName
                                              select a)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem();
        string str = Membership.GetUser(result.UserId).ToString();

        item.Text = result.FirstName.Trim() + " " + result.Surname.Trim() + " (" + str + ")";

        if (!result.IsApproved)
        {
            item.Text = item.Text + " (Not Active)";
            //item.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;"); before
        }
        item.Value = result.UserId.ToString();

        this.AddMultipleUsers.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

in the first image, the checkboxlist is fully populated. Before link to code^[image]

in the second after I un-comment this line //item.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;"); 
then checkboxlist is the same size as the first image but, there is large spaces between
the users that are active, when you scroll down you see them randomly.[image]

I want to remove the blank items within the checkbox list and make the other valid entries to be moved up like a normally populated checkbox list

Thank you

Comment: are you working on .net framework 3.5 + ?

Comment: I am working on .net framework 3.0. But I will check quick.

Comment: Yes, I am working on .net framework 3.5.

Comment: then i will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add a `where` condition to your select statement:

```
this.AddMultipleUsers.Items.Clear();
foreach (GetAllLoginUsersResult result in from a in this.db.GetAllLoginUsers(null)
                                          orderby a.FirstName
                                          where a.IsApproved==true
                                          select a)
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem();
    string str = Membership.GetUser(result.UserId).ToString();

    item.Text = result.FirstName.Trim() + " " + result.Surname.Trim() + " (" + str + ")";

    item.Value = result.UserId.ToString();
    this.AddMultipleUsers.Items.Add(item);
}
```

now you are only cycling through the active users, and no longer need to hide the inactive ones.

Comment: To answer your question above: I am not using a list as such. In the foreach loop is where I get my values from the database, as that GetAllLoginUsersResult is a class that is set up the same as the stored procedure in the database where the variables are @XXX. But I will give this a try now, if it works I will let you know. And Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: It will work, and it was a retorical question. Your sql statement returns a realtime pointer list and is valid as long as the database connection is open, linq will just filter it and return the relevant items  :)

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought as much that it was rhetorical question. But now, how is the variable result going to be detected (as being created) if the result variable is in the same line as the result variable at the end of the foreach loop. In short, it says it does not  exist in the current contexts?

Comment: Well it will work, i probably made some syntax errors as i was writing it from memory, i will test it out when i get to a pc. Meanwhile, try separating it to statements as in the beginning of my post and loop through mySortedList

Comment: Alright I got it working, but when I run it as search for true, it gives me a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, on code else where in my class.

Comment: here is the code affected:         private string FindLoginUserDescriptionFromId(string strLoginUserId)
        {
            string s = "";
            for (int b = 0; b < AddMultipleUsers.Items.Count; b++)
            {
                s = this.AddMultipleUsers.Items.FindByValue(strLoginUserId).Text.Trim();
            }
            return s;
        }

Comment: i just realized i gave you a complicated solution to a simple problem xD i changed my code have a look

Comment: Like if it is getting now values when i search for true, but if I do it for false it works.

Comment: Ok i see, it still does the same as i described above, before your comment.

Comment: can you debug and tell me which object exactly is null ?

Comment: debug will be hard, for the reason being, I am running this into a .dll extension rather than a program exe. but I will give you the error report for it.

Comment: this code is running to null:                     s = this.AddMultipleUsers.Items.FindByValue(strLoginUserId).Text.Trim();

Comment: but your code is running smooth without the `where` statement yes ? is it possible that the `IsApproved` attribute is null in your database for some users?

Comment: yes, it runs with no problem. If you consider 0 as null then there is alot of them, but the program checks if it is a 0 then false and if 1 then true.

Comment: by null i mean DBNull.Value, if you open the db using visual studio and it shows *NULL*, if its 0 then it is not null.

Comment: I just ran a query in my database to look for null values and there is non. It is strange.

Comment: sorry i thought of something else when you asked that.

Comment: Its like when I put the where statement to check for IsApproved(being true), it ignors the ones that are true and just says its null

Comment: the 1 and 0 are stored as int, or varchar ?

Comment: the moment I make that where a.IsApproved == false, then it works no problem, cause then there is over 100 entries in the checkboxlist.

Comment: do you get any results if you compare against true ? does it enter the foreach loop? maybe it does not get any results at all

Comment: If I change it to look for true, to me it looks like it does enter into the for loop, but then it kicks out in a different section of the program giving me an error saying:   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: can you follow the stack trace and check on which line inside this foreach loop does it kick out ?

Comment: Ok i just noticed that it does not kick out of the for loop, it is somewhere else in the program it throws that exception.

Comment: private string FindLoginUserDescriptionFromId(string strLoginUserId)
        {
            string s = "";
            for (int b = 0; b < AddMultipleUsers.Items.Count; b++)
            {
                s = this.AddMultipleUsers.Items.FindByValue(strLoginUserId).Text.Trim();
            }
            return s;
        }

Comment: the above code is where it kicks out.
here is the line:
s = this.AddMultipleUsers.Items.FindByValue(strLoginUserId).Text.Trim();

Comment: in that case, it seems that you are trying to find a login description for a non active user, since that user is no longer included in the `AddMultipleUsers` collection, the `FindByValue` returns null and then you are trying to access the text attribute of a null reference.you should check if `FindByValue` returns an object, and only then access the text attribute. otherwise the user is not active and is not in the list

Comment: you could return a "this user is no longer active" if the function returns null, if you do need the description then you should search for the user directly in the database